# Add a hover state, to a class that targets a child with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to add a class that changes rules for a child class using Javascript. I have figured out how to add it using CSS but not Javascript. Once added in CSS, I can remove it with JS by simply using the classname that comes before the hover pseudo-class. However, adding it back after it has been removed in the same manner doesn't actually work. I'm guessing this is a syntax issue but I can't figure out the correct way to do it. Any ideas?

```js
function hideTooltip(){
  elementName.classList.remove( 'tooltip' );
}

function showTooltip(){
  elementName.classList.add( 'tooltip' );
}
```

```css
.tooltip:hover .tool-name{
  display: inline;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, so it looks like it actually was working. I had some specificity issues causing it not to take when I tried to add it back.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding and removing **elements** when you use [add](https://api.jquery.com/add/) or [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) which is definitely not the same as adding or removing **classes**.

You need to use [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/), or [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), or [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) accordingly instead

```
function hideTooltip(){
  elementName.classList.removeClass( 'tooltip' );
}

function showTooltip(){
  elementName.classList.addClass( 'tooltip' );
}
```

Comment: Looks like addClass is only in the jquery library. I'm trying to avoid that if I can. I'll stick with classList.add unless there is a reason to implement jquery but thanks for the info.